# Angular - How to bind changes to html from variable when manipulating array

Tags: arrays, angular, two-way-binding

I want to make the selection element by giving the array model. However, it doesn't bind to html selection element, when I change(only push or splice) the array model. I made two samples and added on stackblitz. Please check  and resolve my problem :)

```
HTML:
<select multiple [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<button (click)="push()">
  Push
</button>

TS:
selected = ['A', 'B'];
push() {
    this.selected.push('C');
}
```

[samples](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7s4hrb-dvxdnt?file=app/select-value-binding-example.html)

Comment: you can use json pipe like `<span>Test: {{ test | json }}</span>`

Comment: Welcome to SO, although it's very good to provide stackblitz link but also you need to provide minimal code in your question, so that if the other devs search the google and get to your question they see some code, even when stackblitz link is not available any more

Comment: hi, my problem isn't about showing. my problem is the only bind to html. thanks for answer.

Comment: @RezaRahmati added, thank you.

Comment: @Picaroon awesome, also please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

When you push an item to array the reference of the array doesn't change, and angular doesn't know that it has been changed one solution is to create a new array each time with same members `this.array = [...this.array]`, which is not that hard. see below code, which fixes your issue

```
push() {
    this.selected.push('C');
    this.selected = [...this.selected];
    this.test.push({ name: 'hgf' })
    this.test = [...this.test];
  }
  splice() {
    this.selected.splice(0, 1);
    this.selected = [...this.selected];
    this.test.splice(0, 1);
    this.test = [...this.test];
  }
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7s4hrb-xwfpsf)

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. A very simple example I showed in the stackblitz. If I do as you say, the select element throws up the onSelectionChange event count of elements of the array. I think this is not the best practice.

Comment: I copy paste the code from your stack blitz when I fixed that